# Loaded music disappears after downloading

Tags: itunes, music

I like to use a site that features songs from TV and movies. I have these saved to my laptop into my iTunes library.

Shortly after I place these songs in my iTunes library, they seem to disappear and I cannot find them anywhere on my laptop.

This same thing happened when I downloaded songs from a 'drop card' that I bought from a local band. I downloaded the songs into iTunes and the next day the song was displayed in my iTunes library but the computer said that it could not locate the song and did I want to look for it? Yeah, right, like I have a chance of finding it!

So where are these songs going?

Answer (score 1):

Hm that sounds really weird. I can only try to give you some suggestions...

I assume you already searched in "Finder" for the missing file? What you maybe could do is to search via terminal from the root directory:

```
find / -name "myfile" -print
```

And you are sure that it is the "right" iTunes library? Maybe, it is copied to a library to an external hard drive of yours? The folder where you are copying it to is in your `iTunes -> Preferences -> Advanced -> iTunes Media Folder Location`
folder?